# UI Truncation on Localized Win7 Versions

Tags: c#, .net, interface, internationalization

I have a 2 UI developed in C# .NET 3 and Wise Installer respectively. The UI is a Page of Wizard. This works perfectly alright on Win 7 English OS. But when I deploy the app on Win7 Korean or Chinese. I see the truncation.

I see the issue even if I hard code the Font as the default font for any localized OS is different.

Other Things, I tried were - Changing the Windows Theme, Changing the resolution. But the Issue remains there.

I want to understand what could be the reason for such change? Is there any official documentation regarding such a behavior? What could be the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to get a "fixed size" form like a wizard to behave itself when the OS DPI setting is changed, and I'd imagine you may have similar problems with different language editions of Windows. (The biggest difficulties are having to constantly reboot your PC to test it, and that the Forms Designer is affected by the current OS/Font/DPI settings, so you can't edit the form in your test environment because then it won't work when you return to your coding environment!)

Forms are scaled by default based on the font and DPI settings on the destination computer. In the Form properties, look for the AutoScaleMode option, and try setting it to "DPI" or "None" instead of "Font".

Another option that may help is the MinimumSize property, which may help you to stop the window becoming too small while still allowing it to grow for "Large Fonts" modes.